# Using the same database in all activities Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

i am new to android. i already created a database and store some data there. What i want is that the stored data in my database, I want to print it all out in another activity.

I don't know how to do this sharing of one database in all activities. I did research but they are all complex codes that i don't understand. Greatly appreciated if you could give me some simple codes about it. Thanks

im using SQLLite database.

Comment: Database is common to the app and not specific to an activity.

Comment: Hi, database is common for the whole app, if you have emulator or some rooted device you can check that in aplication data folder that there is a database section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same database throughout the whole app. In order to create an interaction bridge between your Activity and Database, you need to utilise few classes like ContentResolver and ContentProvider. Here is android example of how to create a ContentProvider -

[Creating ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html)

You can also read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm) blog for better understanding about how things work in Android in terms of Database.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

The same database can be used in all activities.You need to create a class through which you can access the database.Before I can tell you how to retrieve data you need to tell me somethings.You have written that you have already created a database.Have you created an external database and are trying use the database from assets folder or have you created an internal database in your android application?

Comment: i used SQLLite database.

Comment: Go through this tutorial and check Dbhelper class given in the tutorial       http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm